# barcodedetector создание объекта

Tags: android, firebase, barcode

Всем привет. Пытаюсь сделать приложение, которое сканирует баркоды с камеры. Проблема при создании обЪекта barcodedetector. Не могу понять почему. Но как только в отладке доходит до создания barcodedetector приложение закрывается.

```
 class ImageAnalyser : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {


    private fun degreesToFirebaseRotation(degrees: Int): Int = when (degrees) 
     {
        0 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_0
        90 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_90
        180 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_180
        270 -> FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_270
        else -> throw Exception("Rotation must be 0, 90, 180, or 270.")
    }


    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy?, degrees: Int) {

        val mediaImage = imageProxy?.image
        val imageRotation = degreesToFirebaseRotation(degrees)

        if (mediaImage != null) {
            val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, 
 imageRotation)
            val optionsBundle =

    FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder().setBarcodeFormats(
                    FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_ALL_FORMATS
                ).build()

            val detector: FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector by lazy {
                FirebaseVision.getInstance().visionBarcodeDetector
            }

            fun detectInImage(Image: FirebaseVisionImage): 
Task<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>> {
                return detector.detectInImage(image)
            }

            val result = detectInImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                    for (barcode in barcodes) {
                        val bounds = barcode.boundingBox
                        val corners = barcode.cornerPoints

                        val rawValue = barcode.rawValue


                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    exception.message

                }


        }
    }
   }


01/27 09:52:05: Launching 'app' on Samsung Galaxy S7 API 26.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.barcodescaner/com.barcodescaner.LiveScan" -a          android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
 Waiting for application to come online: com.barcodescaner.test | com.barcodescaner
Waiting for application to come online: com.barcodescaner.test | com.barcodescaner
Waiting for application to come online: com.barcodescaner.test | com.barcodescaner
Connecting to com.barcodescaner
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8627', transport: 'socket'
 Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/ActivityThread: Application com.barcodescaner is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/zygote: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10089(u0_a89) com.barcodescaner identical 4 lines
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1395)
 W/FirebaseApp: Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
D/Camera2Initializer: CameraX initializing with Camera2 ...
I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 2609(1351KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 78% free, 426KB/1962KB, paused 12.607ms total 60.301ms
D/CameraRepository: Added camera: 0
D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and online use case: [] for camera: 0
D/CameraRepository: Added camera: 1
D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and online use case: [] for camera: 1
I/zygote: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:       Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
    at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2421)
    at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:779)
    at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
    at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
    at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at void com.barcodescaner.LiveScan.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LiveScan.kt:56)
    at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6975)
    at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.barcodescaner-wd1D87fIy2NXDNQ1zMkW4A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.barcodescaner-wd1D87fIy2NXDNQ1zMkW4A==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.barcodescaner-wd1D87fIy2NXDNQ1zMkW4A==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2421)
    at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:779)
    at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
    at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
    at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
```

I/zygote:     at void com.barcodescaner.LiveScan.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LiveScan.kt:56)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6975)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2421)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:779)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at void com.barcodescaner.LiveScan.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LiveScan.kt:56)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6975)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1213)
I/zygote:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.barcodescaner-wd1D87fIy2NXDNQ1zMkW4A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.barcodescaner-wd1D87fIy2NXDNQ1zMkW4A==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.barcodescaner-wd1D87fIy2NXDNQ1zMkW4A==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2421)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:779)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at void com.barcodescaner.LiveScan.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LiveScan.kt:56)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6975)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
I/zygote:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2421)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:779)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at void com.barcodescaner.LiveScan.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LiveScan.kt:56)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6975)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.barcodescaner-wd1D87fIy2NXDNQ1zMkW4A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.barcodescaner-wd1D87fIy2NXDNQ1zMkW4A==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.barcodescaner-wd1D87fIy2NXDNQ1zMkW4A==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2421)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:779)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at void com.barcodescaner.LiveScan.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (LiveScan.kt:56)
I/zygote:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6975)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:767)
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x99e56ec0, tid 23413
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x955c56a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x955c56a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x88045200)
I/Camera2CameraInfo: Device Level: INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=21KB
    After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=21KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
W/zygote: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])

Comment: Какие логи? Еще раз убедись что сделал все как в инструкции

Comment: Явно проблема в создании объекта. Как его и где не создаю. Все утыкается в него

Comment: без логов никак, там наверняка код ошибки есть

Comment: Нашел еще один мануал, по нему попробую в понедельник теперь уже наверно.

Comment: Я бы и рад все сделать по инструкции, но тогда код дажен не компилится.

Comment: Возможно что-то напутал в  build.gradle. В Android studio есть помощник (Tools>Firebase) который умеет сам подключать все что нужно. Нужно все сделать точно по инструкции !

Comment: А, то есть теперь в студию фактически интегрированы и инструкции)). Удобно. Попробую

Comment: Спасибо, barcode создался))